# How to pass configuration from driver to executors in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example.

```scala
object App {

  var confValue: String = ""

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // set conf by cmd args
    confValue = args.head
    // do some context init
    val dataset: Dataset[Int] = ???
    dataset.foreach { row =>
      // get conf from executor
      println(confValue)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get conf on executors, but actually it can't be done because `confValue` only has been modified on the driver

I know I can pass `confValue` to executors by local variable like this.

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // set conf by cmd args
    val confValue = args[0]
    // do some context init
    val dataset: Dataset[Int] = ???
    dataset.foreach { row =>
      // get conf from executor
      println(confValue)
    }
  }
```

But my spark job is huge. It has so many functions. I can't pass confValue everywhere as a local variable. For example:

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // set conf by cmd args
    val confValue = args[0]
    // do some context init
    val dataset: Dataset[Int] = ???
    dataset.foreach { row =>
      doSomeLogic(row)
    }
  }

  private def doSomeLogic(row: Int): Unit = {
    // get conf from executor
    println(confValue)
  }
```

There is so many `doSomeLogic`. So I can't pass `confValue` to all of them.
Is there some way to pass `confValue` to every executors automatically?

---

updated 1

My spark code may like below

```scala
object App {

  /** env flag, will be inited by cmd args, and be used in executors */
  var env: String = ""
  val spark: SparkSession = ???

  import spark.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // read env from args
    env = args.head

    var ds: Dataset[Int] = ???
    ds = doLogic1(ds)
    ds = doLogic2(ds)
    doLogic3(ds)
  }

  private def doLogic1(ds: Dataset[Int]): Dataset[Int] = {
    ds.map { row =>
      // env will be used here
      ???
    }
  }

  private def doLogic2(ds: Dataset[Int]): Dataset[Int] = {
    ds.map { row =>
      // env will be used here
      ???
    }
  }

  private def doLogic3(ds: Dataset[Int]): Dataset[Int] = {
    ds.map { row =>
      // env will be used here
      ???
    }
  }
}
```

`env` will be inited in `main`, and will be used in some of `doLogicN` functions. My spark project is a large project with many `doLogicN` functions, so passing the `env` flag to every `doLogicN` function will change too many codes.

What is the simplest way to pass the `env` flag to all `doLogicN` functions?

The most difficult point is that the `env` will be used in executors. If it will only be used in drivers I can pass it to everywhere by global `env` variable. But it won't work well in executors because the global `env` variable hasn't been inited. It only be inited in the driver side.

Comment: you can broadcast the confValue to all the executors and use that using confValue.value in the code where you are using confValue

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya Thanks for your comment! I did some search about broadcast. It seems that the broadcast variable can only be created through `SparkContext`, which means this variable must come from a "local variable" status. So it's similar to the situation of my second code. But how to solve the problem shown by my third code? How to broadcast the `confValue` to **ALL** exectuors? Could you show some example code please :)

Comment: please check my answer below to see how you can use broadcast to have value on all the executors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my question.

The conf can be set by Spark Conf while committing the spark job, such as `spark.my.env=env_1`

It can be read by `SparkEnv.get.conf.get("spark.my.env")`, which has the same effect between the driver and executors, after `sparkContext` has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below to broadcast the value to all the executors and then based on your requirement and can use it as you want. Also instead of using for each you should use for each partition if you want to process data for each partition in parallel.

Below is the sample code of how you can broadcast a value and use it:

```
//Sample data created
val df = Seq(("a","2020-01-16 08:55:50"),("b","2020-01-16 08:57:37"),("c","2020-01-16 09:00:13"),("d","2020-01-16 09:01:32"),("e","2020-01-16 09:03:32"),("f","2020-01-16 09:06:56")).toDF("ID","timestamp")
//check the partitions that a datframe has
df.rdd.partitions.size
//broadcast the value that you want to broadcast
val confValue = "Test"
val bdct_confvalue = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(confValue);
//using the broadcasted value on each executors nodes as required
df.foreachPartition(partition => {
  println("Confvalue partition =" +bdct_confvalue.value)
 }
)
```

Also to see the value printed in the logs you would have to see the executors logs and not the driver logs as you would not be able to see this print statement in the driver logs. you would also not able to see this in any notebook like Jupyter or Databricks notebook as they show driver logs on the UI.

Comment: `bdct_confvalue` is passed by closure. But my spark project is a large project which has thousands of lines. `bdct_confvalue` may be inited at the beginning, but it may be used in another file or in different stages of spark tasks, beyond many function calls... Pass it by closure may change too many codes. So I wonder if there is some way to modify a global variable in the driver and make it take effect in executors

Comment: if you want to make use of the variable that is updated and you wat to keep track of it then you can use accumulators for that case. But don't understand why you would need something that is changing and want to keep track of it. If it is like counter then making use of accumulator makes sense but for your use case I don't know because there is not much clarity on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to deal with two environment with one code. I think the current env flag can be passed by cmd args. With different env flags, my spark job will go to different functions, which may be running in executors. So I'm finding one way to make all executors know the current env flag

Comment: but that env flag that you pass as a argument is not going to change for any specific run. env flag could have different values that you can pass as as argument at the start of your spark application and that would remain same for the whole run. For example you run in dev environment then your env flag would have the value of Dev and if you run in prod environment then env flag would have a value of Prod.

Comment: It won't change after inited in `main` by cmd args. But before `main`, it will be empty because I don't know the current env. Please see the update of the question description for more information.

Comment: In that case broadcasting the variable should work.. Simple using the if condition would also work as it would have the data on the executors only whether it is dev or prod instead you can broadcast connection string so that you can perform read as well as rights from all executors.

Comment: It seems that broadcasting the variable means I need declare a local `env` variable in every `doLogicN` function which will use the `env` variable? It may result in too many code change...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228196/discussion-between-nikunj-kakadiya-and-ericxluo).